# In Spring how to send enum as response in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have Enum Class. I Need to send a Enum class Response from the Spring controller. 
I am not able understand how to sent class as Response in spring controller. Please help me for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add anything which Jackson can de-serialize in a reponse

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/monday")
    public ResponseEntity<DayOfWeek> monday() {
        return new ResponseEntity<DayOfWeek>(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/days")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DayOfWeek>> days() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<DayOfWeek>>(Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.values()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

You can prove this to yourself with the following test, just do the Jacskon de-serialization manually

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void monday() throws Exception {
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/monday").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(json)));
    }

    @Test
    public void days() throws Exception {
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.values()));
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/days").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(json)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to Day enum: the java.time.DayOfWeek enum already covers this.

Comment: I want to test that handler by using Junit test case can you please tell me how to test. I am new to Junit. My requirement is to test that responce in Junit. Thanks for your  help.....

Comment: @PeterWalser could you please answer to my another requriment  in below link :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987192/how-to-return-all-entities-by-id-in-spring-form-spring-controller

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna return all enum values than try something like this:

```
@GetMapping("enum")
public List<MyEnum> paymentMethods() {
    return Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
}

public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST, SECOND, THIRD;
}
```

Comment: I want to test that handler by using Junit test case can you please tell me how to test. I am new to Junit. My requirement is to test that responce in Junit. Thanks for your help.....