# How to Return all entities by Id In Spring form spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have A,B,C,E,D services have collect all that service from controller by company id and return that service as response to    WebUtils.writeJSONResponse.
What ever service i am getting form services like aService and bService. I have to store List DTO Object and i have to set in the setters of that EntityListResponce and i have to send that response to WebUtils.writeJSONResponse.

```
@RequestMapping("/getAllEntitys.htm")
public void getAllEntities(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        ZSession zSession = getZSession(request);
        Long companyId = zSession.getCompanyId();

        EntityListResponce entityListResponce = new EntityListResponce();

        List<ADTO> aList = aService.getAllA(companyId);
        List<BDTO> bList = bService.getAllB(companyId);
        List<CListDTO> cList = cService.getAllC(companyId);
        List<DDTO> dDTO = dService.getAllD(companyId);
        EDTO eDTO = eService.getEcompanyId);

        entityListResponce.setADTO(aList );
        entityListResponce.setBDTO(bList );
        entityListResponce.setCDTO(cList );
        entityListResponce.setDDTO(dDTO );
        entityListResponce.setEDTO(eDTO );

        WebUtils.writeJSONResponse(response,
                getSerializer(request, EXCLUDE_FILES).deepSerialize(entityListResponce));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        writeException(request, response, e);
    }
}
```

But i not able get proper output when i am debugging by Junit.

```
@Test
public void testAllEntities() throws Exception {

    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/getAllEntitys.htm");
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    invoiceController.getAllEntities(request, response);
    JSONArray jsonArr = getResponseJSONArray(response);
    Assert.assertNotNull(jsonArr);
}
```

Please help me it is proper way to do or not.Thanks

Comment: please hep for this

Comment: There are a few things missing from your description which makes it difficult to answer. For example, what does `i not able get proper output` mean exactly? Incorrect data? Missing data? Anyway, just a wild thought, you have a `getZSession(request);` call, and from the result you then extract the `companyId` that's used in all the subsequent service calls. I don't see anything like that setup in your test...

Comment: Morfic: What ever service i am getting form services like aService and bService. I have to store List DTO Object and i have to set in the setters of that  EntityListResponce and i have to send that response to WebUtils.writeJSONResponse.

Comment: This does not answer any of my questions... Let's take them one at a time: what is not going as expected in your test, as in what's failing or what is happening incorrectly?